# Align these ordered list and list element in a horizontal line

Tags: css

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<div>
  <ol class="sortable">
    <li id="list_1" class="nob"><div>A</div>
      <ol>
        <li id="list_2"><div>1</div></li>
        <li id="list_3"><div>2</div></li>
        <li id="list_4"><div>3</div></li>
        <li id="list_5"><div>4</div></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li id="list_6" class="nob"><div>B</div>
      <ol>
        <li id="list_7"><div>1</div></li>
        <li id="list_8"><div>2</div></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I want the output to be as :

|A|1|2|3|4|B|1|2|

Can anyone help me write the CSS for the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic solution:

```
.nob, .nob div, .nob ol, .nob li { display: inline; /* or inline-block */ }
```

Use `inline` if you don't need to control vertical margins. Otherwise you should consider using `inline-block`.

Comment: should add `.nob{float: left;}` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
.sortable li, .sortable li div, .sortable li ol  {
    float:left;
}
```